# Execute command from git configuration

Tags: git, macos, git-config

On macOS, the tool [`ghi`](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi) (GitHub Issues on the command line) adds the following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[ghi]
    token = !security find-internet-password -a username -s github.com -l 'ghi token' -w
```

It is my understanding that by starting with a `!`, it means that is a shell command. And indeed it is, as executing it returns the correct authentication token (stored in the macOS [Keychain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_%28Mac_OS%29)). But running `git config --get ghi.token` returns the command itself (with `!`), instead of its *result*, which was what I was expecting because it seems that `ghi` would use that to retrieve the key.

What is the `git` command, if any, to return the result of the command, instead of the command itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command; `ghi` reads the configuration value, strips the '!' and executes the result:

```rb
    value = ENV[var] || `git config #{flags} #{key}`
    value = `#{value[1..-1]}` if value.start_with? '!'
```

see [ghi repository](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi/blob/0bf0e97016b36d8746fabd6dd71f79e94134407f/ghi#L131-L132)

git uses `!` at some places the mark configuration values as programs instead of plain value; but there is not automatic evaluation behind.